# Google Sheet Script: How to remove duplicate but only apply to the older entries?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that pulls in data from a 3rd party source. The new data is added and appended to the same sheet everyday. I have set up a trigger onChange with the script below:

```
function removeDuplicates() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange("A:Z");
range.removeDuplicates([1,2]);
}
```

E.g. column A is date, column B is Name.

For example, my sheet looks like this when new data is added.

| Name | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 3-Feb-21 | 100 |
| Tom | 3-Feb-21 | 200 |
| Sam | 3-Feb-21 | 300 |
| John | 4-Feb-21 | 100 |
| Tom | 4-Feb-21 | 200 |
| Sam | 4-Feb-21 | 300 |
| Tom | 4-Feb-21 | 201 |
| Sam | 4-Feb-21 | 301 |

The last two rows are the new entries, which will deleted if I run my current script.
Is there a way to make sure that it only removes the older entries? e.g.

| Name | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 4-Feb-21 | 200 |
| Sam | 4-Feb-21 | 300 |

The desired result should be:

| Name | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 3-Feb-21 | 100 |
| Tom | 3-Feb-21 | 200 |
| Sam | 3-Feb-21 | 300 |
| John | 4-Feb-21 | 100 |
| Tom | 4-Feb-21 | 201 |
| Sam | 4-Feb-21 | 301 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- [removeDuplicates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removeDuplicates()) starts from the top so it will remove the most recent values, but you want to keep the recent values and delete the older ones.
- Therefore I used [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) to find the last rows at which each name appears.
- You mentioned that you have an `onChange` trigger installed for this function. Please keep in mind that `onChange` trigger **responds only to user changes**. Namely, if a script makes changes to the file, the `onChange` trigger will never fire. Therefore, I would advice you to put the code of this answer to your current script that fetches data, so after the update of the data, the code will remove the duplicates.

### Solution:

I think your desired result should be this :

[image]

If that is the case, then this code will work for you:

```
function removeDups(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const names = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat()
  const unames = [...new Set(names)];
  const fdata = [];     
  unames.forEach(name=>{
        let dataFinder = sh.createTextFinder(name);         
        let res = dataFinder.findAll(); 
        if(res.length>0){
          let matched = sh.getRange(res[res.length-1].getRow(), 1, 1, 3).getValues();
          fdata.push(matched.flat());
        };        
   });
   sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
   sh.getRange(2,1,fdata.length,fdata[0].length).setValues(fdata);
}
```

### Updated Solution:

```
function removeDups(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const rng = sh.getRange("A2:C"+sh.getLastRow());
  const raw_data = rng.getValues().reverse();
  rng.setValues(raw_data);
  rng.removeDuplicates([1,2]);
  const sorted_rng= sh.getRange("A2:C"+sh.getLastRow());
  const sorted_data = sorted_rng.getValues().reverse();
  sorted_rng.setValues(sorted_data);  
}
```

Comment: Hi Marios, thanks for the answer. My desired data is actually different. I have edited the original thread to include the desired data. The data was pull in using a 3rd party service e.g. mailparser, instead of a code.

Comment: @Chris Check the Update Solution. It removes the duplicates and sorts for the date, the names does not actually sort the right way. If that is not an issue let me know. Regarding the `onChange` trigger. Like I said, only **user** edits can trigger an `onChange` function. Nothing else (you name it) either it is a code or 3rd party service or formula or you name it. Only user edits are going to trigger the function. You can actually test it by yourself to see.

Comment: Works like a dream! Thanks Marios!